# What's wrong with strcmp and c_str() here?

Tags: c++, stl, strcmp

The following code is my solution for the [Largest Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/). However it will crash.

If I directly compare `tampa` and `tempb` in `cmp()` by using `tempa > tempb` instead of `strcmp()`, it is OK. So what is wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

bool cmp(string a, string b) {
    string tempa = a + b;
    string tempb = b + a;
    int res = strcmp(tempa.c_str(), tempb.c_str());
    if (res < 0) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}

class Solution {
public:
        string largestNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<string> str;
        string res = "0";

        if (nums.empty()) {
            return res;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << nums[i];
            str.push_back(ss.str());
        }
        sort(str.begin(), str.end(), cmp);
        res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
            res += str[i];
        }

        return res[0] == '0' ? "0" : res;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution sol;
    int data[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    vector<int> nums(data, data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));
    string res = sol.largestNumber(nums);
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is not equivalent to `tempa > tempb`. It is equivalent to `!(tempa < tempb)` or `tempa >= tempb`. And a *"greater than or equal"* comparison does not satisfy the requirements of `std::sort`. Specifically, the comparison needs to be irreflexive, which is to say that for an operand A, `cmp(A, A)` should be false, but with `>=`, it is true.

If you want the `strcmp` equivalent of `tempa > tempb`, then do:

```
return strcmp(tempa.c_str(), tempb.c_str()) > 0;
```

On closer inspection, your comparison is fundamentally broken. Why are you concatenating `a` and `b` together to form temporary strings for comparison? As one simple example of what can go wrong there, an empty string will compare equal to every other string, because:

```
(string("anything") + "") == (string("") + "anything")
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That's it. I didn't know that the `cmp` should be irreflexive before. The comparison is OK here for this problem, because given two integers '12' and '123', I want to tell what is the biggest concatenation, `12123` or `12312`.